# Why does my computer shut down automatically?

Tags: troubleshooting, shutdown

I have 3 year old computer that shuts down automatically after 15 minutes. Since all the fans are working, I don't suspect a heat problem

So what else could cause my computer to shutdown like this?

Comment: please have a look at my edit and try to strive for some better English next time. I can't go and edit every question you ask.

Comment: Might be a virus problem. Google for a virus that shuts down the computer.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot just assume that it is NOT a heat issue.  Just because you hear a fan whirl.  Heat buildup could be caused by dust clogging a fan, or building up around cooling fins (video cards, etc).

Please update what operating system you are running.  In many cases, having a look @ (windows) event logs will give you an idea WHY something shut down.  IT will log those things for you to review, sometimes it could be a failing video driver and it notes something like *ati.dll failed to blah blah* which hints at it being an ati video card issue (yes ati/amd).

Update your question and post more details, otherwise people will just guess.